# JBoss Picketlink - Authentication fails with custom User model

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss

I've been following the JBoss Picketlink 2.5.x [documentation found here](http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html/ch03.html#d5e498) in an attempt to create a custom `User` model for authenticating to my application.  My app is a typical JavaEE 6 application deployed on JBoss EAP 6.2.  I've been able to successfully create the custom `User` model class and am able to persist a user with no problem.  I see my custom attributes reflected in the database as expected.  My custom `User` model looks like this:

```
public class ExtendedUser extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9132382669181464122L;

    @AttributeProperty
    private String uniqueIdentifier = null;

  ...

}
```

...and the code to create a new user account looks like this:

```
ExtendedUser u = new ExtendedUser(username);
u.setFirstName(firstName);
u.setLastName(lastName);
u.setEmail(emailAddress);
u.setUniqueIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

idm.add(u);
idm.updateCredential(u, new Password(password));
```

Additionally, I have a custom Entity model for the user account that looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "UserAccount")
@Table(name = "tbl_user_account", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" }) })
@IdentityManaged({ ExtendedUser.class, Agent.class })
public class UserAccountBean extends BaseAccountIdentityBean implements
        IdentifiedDomainEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -537779599507513418L;

       <snip... irrelevant fields...>

    @Column(length = ValidationConstants.UUID_LEN, unique = true)
    @Unique
    @Length(max = ValidationConstants.UUID_LEN)
    @Index(name = "idx_user_account_uniqueid")
    @AttributeValue(name = "uniqueIdentifier")
    // @NotEmpty
    private String uniqueIdentifier = null;


 ...
```

I see the `uniqueIdentifier` attribute being populated in the database table as expected.  However, whenever I attempt to authenticate using a user created this way, the authentication fails.  Every time.  Is there something else I need to do to make use of my custom `User` object?  Do I have to specify it somewhere when creating my `Identity` or `IdentityManager` instances?  My authentication code is relatively simple and looks like this:

```
@Inject
private DefaultLoginCredentials loginCredentials = null;

    ...

        loginCredentials.setUserId(loginName);
    loginCredentials.setPassword(password);

    AuthenticationResult result = identity.login();
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("authenticate(String, String, String) - AuthenticationResult result=" + result); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
```

As I mentioned, this code fails every time.  I've done the sanity check of double-checking passwords, and I know they are correct.  I don't see any exceptions or errors written to the logs, so I'm unsure what the problem could be.  The code works just fine if I use the standard `User` object provided by the Picketlink library, even if I use the same Entity for the backend database.  It only fails when using `ExtendedUser`, so I'm sure I'm missing something on my end.  Any advice?

**UPDATE:**  It appears that Picketlink 2.6.0 adds a bit more logging.  I've upgraded and it still fails, but now I see the following error messages:

```
14:41:23,133 DEBUG [org.picketlink.idm.credential] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9080-3) Starting validation for credentials [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials][org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@56370e07] using identity store [org.picketlink.idm.jpa.internal.JPAIdentityStore@22ef0c6c] and credential handler [org.picketlink.idm.credential.handler.PasswordCredentialHandler@387a19c9].
14:41:23,134 DEBUG [org.picketlink.idm.credential] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9080-3) PLIDM001003: Trying to find account [user6_4] using default account type [class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User] with property [loginName].
14:41:23,136 DEBUG [org.picketlink.idm.credential] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9080-3) PLIDM001003: Trying to find account [user6_4] using default account type [class org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Agent] with property [loginName].
14:41:23,138 DEBUG [org.picketlink.idm.credential] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9080-3) Account NOT FOUND for credentials [class org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials][org.picketlink.idm.credential.UsernamePasswordCredentials@56370e07].
```

So, it's clear that Picketlink is trying to use the standard `User` object for authentication, rather than my custom object.  That said, how can I tell Picketlink to use my custom `ExtendedUser` object for authenticating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through the same headache as you. I've been trying to add my own user accounts as well. The only reason I was able to get it to work was the fact that you mentioned that PicketLink is trying to find User and Agent type accounts! This means that you have to implement your own PasswordCredentialHandler. Don't worry! You can just copy [this class](https://github.com/picketlink/picketlink/blob/master/modules/idm/api/src/main/java/org/picketlink/idm/credential/handler/AbstractCredentialHandler.java) and [this class](https://github.com/picketlink/picketlink/blob/master/modules/idm/api/src/main/java/org/picketlink/idm/credential/handler/PasswordCredentialHandler.java) to your project. Within the "configureDefaultSupportedAccountTypes" method of the AbstractCredentialHandler, you will see the following:

```
   if (!this.defaultAccountTypes.contains(User.class)) {
        this.defaultAccountTypes.add(User.class);
    }

    if (!this.defaultAccountTypes.contains(Agent.class)) {
        this.defaultAccountTypes.add(Agent.class);
    }
```

Simply add your custom account classes to it like so:

```
if (!this.defaultAccountTypes.contains(CustomUser.class)) {
        this.defaultAccountTypes.add(CustomUser.class);

    }
```

The last thing you have to do is add the PasswordCredentialHandler to the IDMConfigurtion:

```
private void initConfig() {
    IdentityConfigurationBuilder builder = new IdentityConfigurationBuilder();

    builder
        .named("default")
            .stores()
                .jpa()
                    .mappedEntity(
                            AccountTypeEntity.class,
                            RoleTypeEntity.class,
                            GroupTypeEntity.class,
                            IdentityTypeEntity.class,
                            RelationshipTypeEntity.class,
                            RelationshipIdentityTypeEntity.class,
                            PartitionTypeEntity.class,
                            PasswordCredentialTypeEntity.class,
                            AttributeTypeEntity.class,
                            CustomUserEntity.class
                            )
                    .supportGlobalRelationship(Relationship.class)
                    .addContextInitializer(this.contextInitializer)
                    .addCredentialHandler(PasswordCredentialHandler.class)
                    .supportAllFeatures();
    identityConfig = builder.build();
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

So i tried it with PicketLink 2.6.0.Final.  Maybe you should re download AbstractCredentialHandler and add your class to the defaultAccountTypes ArrayList like this:

```
    private void configureDefaultSupportedAccountTypes(final S store) {
        this.defaultAccountTypes = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Account>>();

        for (Class<? extends AttributedType> supportedType : store.getConfig().getSupportedTypes().keySet()) {
            if (!Account.class.equals(supportedType) && Account.class.isAssignableFrom(supportedType)) {
                this.defaultAccountTypes.add((Class<? extends Account>) supportedType);
            }
        }

        //Add your CustomUser.class to the list
        if (!this.defaultAccountTypes.contains(CustomUser.class)) {
            this.defaultAccountTypes.add(CustomUser.class);
        }

        if (this.defaultAccountTypes.isEmpty()) {
            throw MESSAGES.credentialNoAccountTypeProvided();
        }
    }
```

**Alternative**:
I don dont think you have to do the above if you don't want to.  When you are configuring your IdentityConfig, you can just add supported types like this:

```
    IdentityConfigurationBuilder builder = new IdentityConfigurationBuilder();

    builder
        .named("default")
            .stores()
                .jpa()
                    .supportType(CustomUser.class)  
                    .mappedEntity( 

    ...
```